# Pump motor interference with PIC microcontroller

Tags: pic, interference

I am building a fermentation chamber for sourdough which has a heating element and a 5v mini-pump for humidity. Both are controller by a PIC16 microcontroller. Without the pump all is well, but as soon as the pump kicks in the microcontroller goes haywire.
The combination of a microcontroller and a motor is know to be fragile (from what I gather from reading similar questions). However, as far as I can tell I have done everything by the book:

1. The entire system is powered by a 12V power supply that can deliver up to 15A (the heating element requires 10A).
2. The heating element is connected directly to the power supply.
3. The microcontroller (along with the LCD display and temperature sensor) get their power from a DC-DC converter that steps down the 12V to a 5V.
4. The pump gets its power from a *separate* DC-DC converter that also steps down to 5V.

The PIC's VSS and VDD and MCLR pins are connected to small capacitors (100nF and 10nF, respectively), as per the manual.

Any thoughts on where the interference can be coming from?

(Edit: Replaced the unclear image with a diagram. I realize it's not a proper schematic, but hopefully it makes things clear. Some details are omitted, like the MOSFET switch before the pump's converter used to turn it on and off)
[image]

(Edit2: originally wrote 100uF and 10uF for the capacitors connected to the PIC pins, instead of 100nF and 10nF, respectively)

Comment: Hard to tell from the picture but is the grounding a star configuration or daisy-chained?

Comment: You could try grounding the COM output of the DC-DC power supply and making sure there is a flyback diode for the pump. Hard to tell from just photo what's going on.

Comment: A lot of wires running all over the place. I would suspect I/O pins if you have not provided adequate protection.

Comment: Have you determined whether it is a glitch or whether it is a brownout? Disconnect the motor so you control it manually. Does the microcontroller mess up continuously once the motor is running? Or only on motor startup? What is the decoupling capacitor the input and output of the motor power supply?

Comment: Can u show a schematic of your setup?

Comment: Apologies for the unclear image. Complete noob here... The DC converters are LM2596 buck converters from a popular retail site.

Comment: There is little to work on. The issue may be in the parts you don't show or tell. Or in the implementation, such as too long or too thin wring, sharing a lot of current. There is no knowledge how much the pump takes current at startup and if your modules can provide it, because there is no specs to see if they should work or not.

Comment: All of the 12V wires are 16AWG (for the heater element) or 18AWG (the ones that go into the converters). After the conversion everything is thinner, with 24AWG for the power lines and 28AWG for the signals.

Comment: Probably the usual suspects, EMF from the fan not suppressed, lack of decoupling capacitors, no snubber on your relay, lack of ground plane and everything spaced out too far.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I experimented with various capacitor values between the converter and the circuit board the contains the PIC. 10uF seems to do the trick (at least no lower values up to 4.7uF helped). I'm running a long-term experiment to see if it sticks.